# Issue with using index controller in url while using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

In my codeigniter project, I am removing the index.php extension from url using htaccess. Now when I try to call a function/page that is in index folder Eg: http://domain.com/project/index/contactus, it is showing `404 Page Not Found Error`.

My htaccess file is as shown below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule \.htaccess - [F]
RewriteRule (.*)(css\/)(.*)$ $2$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{request_uri} !^index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

**Index Controller:**

```
class Index extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url','timezone_helper'));
        $this->load->library('tank_auth');
        $this->load->library('session');
        timezone();
    }

    function index()
    { 
          $this->load->view('index/index');
    }
    function contactus()
    {
        $data['email']=$this->config->item('webmaster_email', 'tank_auth'); 
        $data['page']='index/contactus';
        $this->load->view('layout/template',$data);
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me to find the solution to this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some server configurations make the application to work only like this `index.php?/$1`, but you can also try `index.php/$1`. An tell us the result. Also, show us the code from the controller.

Comment: I changed `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]` but yet I am getting page not found error.

Comment: And the controller? Where is it?

Comment: Does the url `http://domain.com/project/index/index` work?

Comment: no..It is also returning page not found

Comment: I have run your code on my computer. I'm running Windows 7 with WAMP and I found no problem whatsoever. Both methods are working. Sorry, I cannot help you more. Note: `%{request_uri}` should be `%{REQUEST_URI}`, see [this](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html#REQUEST_URI)

Comment: @machineaddict..Using this htaccess code I am not able to run files outside application folder.How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your .htaccess:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    #RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


    </IfModule>

    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I've had issues when trying to use RewriteBase so I don't anymore (unless I specifically need to).

Also, in **application/config/config.php**
 make `base_url` and `index_page` `= ''`

Hope this helps!